# add workflow to sharepoint list from visual studio

Tags: workflow, development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a custom workflow for an existing list or library with code in visual studio without using his tool for workflow design.
I want to create it programmatically such as CSOM model but in order to specifie stages and action in my workflow.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use SharePoint's workflow engine?

Comment: @Submits is right, why no WF engine? Btw without it you have to use event receivers and your own tasks list, to manage the stages

Comment: because i'im using my own designer